# Can't install gcloud on Amazon Linux : invalid syntax

Tags: python, linux, installation, gcloud, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install gcloud on my EC2 server running Amazon Linux 4.14.47-56.37 64bits, in interactive mode running the following command :

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

The files download correctly, but the install then fails with the following Traceback :

```
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 32, in <module>
    import setup  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py", line 55, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 291
    self.__sections = {section.name: section for section in sections}
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea why this for is causing issues?

I am running python 2.7 (2.7.14) as recommended by Google.

Comment: It looks like the installation script is finding a python version that does not support dictionary comprehension. You may have an old python installation (`2.6` or below) that's getting found before the `2.7`. What do you see when you run `python2 --version`? or even `python --version`?

Comment: That 4.14.47-56.37 is the kernel version; which distro version are you using? Is it Amazon Linux 2 LTS? If you tell us that, we can at least look up what versions of everything it includes, instead of having to guess. Also, did you get Python 2.7 builtin, from Amazon Linux Extras, or from a non-Amazon repo?

Comment: I've tried that with Python 2.7.13 and worked. If you execute `python --version` and `which python` does it point to the correct python version?

Comment: @Abdou and Miguel Ortiz : python --version returns 2.7.14, and which python does point to this one (/usr/bin/python), but python2 --version returns 2.6.9. Can this cause issues?
Edit : Yes it can. I removed python 2.6 and the install completed successfully.

Comment: @abarnert : "Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03", is that the distro? It's not Amazon Linux 2. Got python with yum, package python27 (this version of Amazon Linux has yum built in).

Comment: Did you install the python27-devel package as well as python27? (If not, it may see your 2.7 as incomplete and use your 2.6 instead.)

Comment: @Dino, I would advise against uninstalling a python installation that you did not put there. Most systems come with default python versions that are used by other processes. What you ***should do*** is edit your `PATH` variable to make sure that `python2` points to your `python2.7` installation. Since you've already uninstalled the `2.6` installation, best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of python 2.7 installed on the "python" command, I also had python 2.6 installed on the "python2" command.
Uninstalling python 2.6 solved the issue, Google Cloud install went through without issue on the next try.

Answer (score 2):

You locally update the install.sh file to use python2.7 instead of python2. This worked for me

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone meets this problem again, and if you do not want to uninstall python 2.6 or to modify install.sh, here is a procedure that worked for me on an ec2 instance :

open a new terminal and type :

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

The install should not work as `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2` by default, which leads to Python 2.6. To correct this, enter this command :

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python
```

this links `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` to Python 3.6

then

```
bash google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

and finally

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
```

Once this is done, you can use any gcloud or gsutil command by doing this :

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud <your gcloud command>
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil <your gsutil command>
```

For example, in order to copy a folder from a gs bucket to your ec2 instance :

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil -m cp -r gs://<bucket_name>/path/to/folder /path/on/your/ec2/instance
```

the `-m` option allows fast transfer (I could transfer with an average speed of 81 MiB/s with this option)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi Sam, great first answer! Just putting it out there to read up on [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in case you missed out on anything. Good going though, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Setup yum repo:

```
# Update YUM with Cloud SDK repo information:
sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/google-cloud-sdk.repo << EOM
[google-cloud-sdk]
name=Google Cloud SDK
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOM
# The indentation for the 2nd line of gpgkey is important.
```

Install yum downloader and download the rpm, then install with "--nodeps":

```
yum install yum-utils
yumdownloader google-cloud-sdk-231.0.0-1.el7.noarch
mv 23873bd6e8459ba6e70e96eb8f03f6ac03cd707ce3c80baa8264c714e030c915-google-cloud-sdk-231.0.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm /usr/local/src/google-cloud-sdk-231.0.0-1.el7.noarch
rpm -ivh --nodeps /usr/local/src/google-cloud-sdk-231.0.0-1.el7.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved issue:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python
```